# How to convert a string to NSData

Tags: xamarin.ios, nsdata

i have a string that I use to create a file.  I now need to take that file and get it into an NSData object for sending as an email.

I'm sorry, but I haven't a clue how to get a string into an NSData object!  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `NSData.FromString (string s)`, unless you mean loading a file name that is stored in a string and getting the NSData of that, in which case use `NSData.FromStream (new FileStream (filename, FileMode.Open));`